# Play a Lottie / Bodymovin animation on scroll on an HTML web page

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints, lottie, bodymovin

I have been searching multiple forums looking for a solution to this problem- I am trying to code multiple lottie animations to play when each animation enters the browser window on an HTML web page. Does anyone have a working solution?

I have tried a solution using Waypoint.js but unfortunately I could not get any more than one animation to play with that approach. If anyone knows of a way to get Lottie and Waypoint to play nicely together I would appreciate any suggestions.

I am open to any script suggestions even if they require that I load dependencies to make them work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I should note that I am brand new to Lottie and I am an animator so please leave detailed explanations as I am a beginner with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

After creating an animation, use `anim.goToAndStop(0)` to pause it:

```
const animData = ... // Let's pretend that you loaded this from a .json file
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.className = 'myAnimation';

// Create the animation
const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
  renderer: 'canvas',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  rendererSettings: {
    context: ctx,
    scaleMode: 'noScale',
    clearCanvas: true,
  },
  animationData: animData,
});

// Go to the first frame and pause
anim.goToAndStop(0);
```

Then, you can use something like OnScreen (https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen) to detect when the animation is visible:

```
import OnScreen from 'onscreen';
const os = new OnScreen();

os.on('enter', '.myAnimation', (element, event) => {
    anim.play(); // If animation becomes visible, play it
});

os.on('leave', '.myAnimation', (element, event) => {
    anim.goToAndStop(0); // If animation goes off screen, reset it
});
```

The above applies to a single animation, but with some minor tweaking, it could be extended to multiple animations.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution:

`var container = document.getElementById('graph_ani');
      animData = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
          container: container,
          renderer: 'svg',
          autoplay: false,
          loop: false,
          path : 'graph.json'
      });`

```
var animationStart = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    animData.playSegments([animationStart,animationStart+1], true);
    animationStart++;
}
```

Could use some work to only play when visible and play on scrolldown and reverse on scroll up but works pretty well for a quick snippet.